How to press enter in matinputharness unit tests?
I want to submit my input when pressing enter.
I tried to do it like that:
input.setvalue('test');
const result = await input.host();
await result.sendsKey('enter');
expect(input.getValue()).toBe('');

However, the test fails with this error:
Expected testenter to be '' 


You are sending the text "enter", not a press of the enter key. Try sending "\n"  instead. If that doesn't fix it, please [edit] the question and make it a [mcve].

It works. Thank you so much

I am assuming you want to trigger the submit action of the form programmatically, I tried it out and the form was not submitting when done programmatically.
To test the form reset you just need to call the reset method for the form manually in the test case and validate it. To my knowledge this is the solution, there could be something better.
it('should reset input on submit', async () => {
  const inputs = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatInputHarness);
  const testInput = inputs[0];
  console.log(testInput);
  await testInput.setValue('test');
  expect(await testInput.getValue()).toBe('test');
  component.reset();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  await fixture.whenStable();
  expect(await testInput.getValue()).toBe('');
});

Stackblitz Demo

The code to programmatically trigger the enter event for the input as below.
enterPressed() {
  console.log('enterPressed');
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('asdf');
    // let enterEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    //   key: 'Enter',
    //   keyCode: 13,
    //   which: 13,
    // });

    // this.test.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(enterEvent);
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Enter' });
    // React's way to dispatch
    this.test.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }, 3000);
}

HTML:
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="reset()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      #test
      formControlName="test"
      name="favorite-food"
      (keydown.enter)="enterPressed()"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Stackblitz Demo
